# Is it possible to get two strings from one JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I am trying to build a Yearly Income Calculator (Gross Salary Calculator) and I hit a roadblock. I wanted to know if it is possible to get two different strings from one textField? My code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JPanel panel;
JLabel lbl;
JTextField tf;
public Main() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    lbl = new JLabel();
    tf = new JTextField();
    panel = new JPanel(null);
    setTitle("Yearly Income Calculator");
    setSize(500, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    lbl.setText("How many hours a day do you work?");
    tf.setBounds(25, 65, 135, 20);
    lbl.setBounds(230, 0, 216, 148);
    tf.setVisible(true);
    lbl.setVisible(true);
    panel.add(tf);
    panel.add(lbl);
    add(panel);
    String workHours = tf.getText();
    System.out.println(workHours);
    setVisible(true);
    tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String workHours = tf.getText();
            lbl.setText("How much is your hourly income?");
            String hourlyIncome = tf.getText();
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}
}
```

The current code does not work and when I enter something into the `JTextField`, both strings will be the first thing I entered. I want to modify the code so that `workHours` and `hourlyIncome` are not the first thing I enter.

Disclaimer + Additional information:

I also wanted to warn you, I am a java beginner, so I apologize if I did not inform you of something I should have. But here is some other things that I wanted to mention that are not as important as the other information. I ran a few tests to debug the problem at first (by printing out each of the strings), and I found out that `workHours` is exactly what it should be, the first inputted string. The problem is that `hourlyIncome` is also the first inputted string. It would be great if you could solve my mystery, and preferably give me the code since, as I said, I am a beginner in Java and might need it to understand what you are saying. In other words, a b

Comment: To have more than one string, you need - in your string - a separator (an specific char that delimits the string). Than, you just split the string with that separator.

Comment: Alternatively, don't think of a _sequence_ of questions; think of an _update_ when an event happens, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bswing%5d%20Adder).

Comment: Checking your code, I believe you need a little more research on action listeners for the java swing. The code on method `actionPerformed` does not seem to do what I think you want to do.

Comment: `panel = new JPanel(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). *"I am a java beginner"* GUIs are not for beginners. Best to learn the basics on command line apps.

Comment: If you want to "prompt" a user for information then use a `JOptionPane` to ask each question. See [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples. Otherwise just create a form with a JLabel and JTextField for each question and a JButton to "calculate" the yearly income. Then in the ActionListener for the button you verify that the user entered a value in each of the two text fields. If not you display an error `JOptionPane` and place the caret on the text field in error.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will show you how to do what @camickr suggests.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: BTW - forgot to ask. Why on Earth is the code using a single input field for two datum? How does that make sense, especially to the hapless user? And as to the type of input field: for numeric values, I'd use a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel`.